# How to uninstall Audio Recorder?

Tags: command-line, sound, appmenu

I tried to uninstall Audio Recorder by doing: sudo apt-get remove audio recorder or audiorecorder but I got the following message:

'Unable to locate package audiorecorder'

Could you help please.

The way it was install was sudo apt-get install audio recorder.

Thank you,
Selda

Comment: How you uninstall software depends upon how you originally installed it. Your question should explain how you installed it.

Comment: What does this tell us? `history | grep record` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: you can view all installed packages which mention record by issuing `dpkg -l|grep -i record`   which will show actual packages which contain the string `record`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the correct package name is "audio-recorder". Try that (with the quotes).

Source: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-audio-recorder-ubuntu-2204/

Another way to figure this out would be to use `apt list --installed` piped into `grep`. See
[How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) for details.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much it worked.